# MYSQL + Update ID Column

Tags: mysql

I have a table that looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `language` (
   `idkey` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `english_lang` text,
   `japanese_lang` text,
   PRIMARY KEY (`idkey`),
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1587 ;
```

The 'idkey' is just a number that starts at 1 and increments.

The 'idkey' currently has gaps in the numbering from entries I've removed and I wanted to see if it was possible to run a MySQL command to re-write this column so there are no gaps in the numbering.

eg: rewrite it so it starts at 1 and runnings till the end (around 1400 entries).

thanks

Comment: Looks like idkey should be a primary key, and typically it's a bad idea to start renumbering primary keys.  Is there a specific reason why you want to do this?

Comment: The table is a static table the website it relates too is still in development. Also the primary key doesn't relate to anything else. Just wanted to fix the ordering before I went live but struggle to do so manually as the japanese_lang text field is in unicode and the values are lost when I try to manually update in most editors... Also it would take a long time to update 1400 numbers... Just a nice to have... hopeing someone might know a simple MySQL update command that would be able to re-write a column like this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is against standard practices to try to fill in these "missing numbers". You need to consider that they were once assigned to something. Assigning them now to something else could potentially lead to problems--especially if you're not using foreign key constraints and have some bad data sitting around.

If you are in a situation where you tested some data and now want to take things live, you can reset the auto-increment by running `Alter Table TABLENAME AUTO_INCREMENT=1` (or any other number) or you can drop and recreate the table. If it has been in production I would recommend against resetting or trying to "fill in the gaps".

In the interest of completeness I believe you can insert a specific number in a normally auto incrementing column by including it in your insert statement. The next auto increment number should pick up from the one you specified. If it's already taken this will cause you problems.

If you really just want to close up gaps the easiest way is to create a new table with the same structure. Then run a query like:

```
INSERT INTO 
    newtable (column2, column3, column4,...) 
VALUES 
    SELECT column2, column3, column4,... FROM oldtable;
```

The drop the old table and rename the new table. The gaps will be filled in and your auto increment number will be at the "correct" place.

**BUT REALLY YOU SHOULD LEAVE GAPS FROM DELETED RECORDS IN PLACE.**

Comment: Perfect answer. Don't fill in the gaps, as there is meaning in them (something was once there).

Comment: understand - however the table isn't live and the key doesn't relate to anything. tried your alter table command and the numbering remained fragmented....

Comment: The alter table command simply returns it to whatever you specify, so the next ID will pick up from there. It won't automatically pick the next empty ID. 

The simplest thing for you to do would be to create a new table with the same structure and then insert the data from your current table, minus the ID column. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: thankyou and I'll remember about leaving the gaps... appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it beacuse primary key is single for each row and one thing more if your column is auto increment then you can't do this, manually you can do it. But you are asking about row entery but syntax is related to create table.