# How delete row on SQL DataBase

Tags: android, mysql, sql, sql-server, android-listview

I have a `ListView` with a `SQL DataBase`. The values for it can be added dynamically with two `EditText`.

I want know how to delete a row in my `SQL DataBase`. Now I can just delete a row by the rowId, so the whole row with all values will be deleted. But I want that just the row is deleted so there so that there will be consecutive numbers.

For example a `ListView`.

```
1 Text1
2 Text2
3 Text3
4 Text4
```

With my code it would like that if I would delete row 3:

```
1 Text1
2 Text2
4 Text4
```

But I want that it look like when I delete row 3:

```
1 Text1
2 Text2
3 Text4
```

My code :

*MainActivity*

```
private void listViewItemLongClick() {
        ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        myList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked, final int position, final long id) {

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                        //Set header
                        builder.setTitle("delete");
                        builder.setMessage("Are you sure ? ");
                                //set the OK button with an onClickListener
                        builder.setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            //edit the userinput
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                myDb.deleteRow(id);
                                populateListView();
                            }
                        }).setNegativeButton("no", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        // Do nothing.
                    }
                }).show();

                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

*DBAdapter*

```
public class DBAdapter {

    private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter"; //used for logging database version changes

    // Field Names:
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_WDH = "task";
    public static final String KEY_KG = "date";

    public static final String[] ALL_KEYS = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_WDH, KEY_KG};

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dbToDo";
    public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "mainToDo";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2; // The version number must be incremented each time a change to DB structure occurs.

    //SQL statement to create database
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SQL =
            "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE
                    + " (" + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                    + KEY_WDH + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                    + KEY_KG + " TEXT"
                    + ");";

    private final Context context;
    private DatabaseHelper myDBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;


    public DBAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.context = ctx;
        myDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    // Open the database connection.
    public DBAdapter open() {
        db = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    // Close the database connection.
    public void close() {
        myDBHelper.close();
    }

    // Add a new set of values to be inserted into the database.
    public long insertRow(String task, String date) {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_WDH, task);
        initialValues.put(KEY_KG, date);

        // Insert the data into the database.
        return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    // Delete a row from the database, by rowId (primary key)
    public boolean deleteRow(long rowId) {
        String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
        return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, where, null) != 0;
    }

    // Return all data in the database.
    public Cursor getAllRows() {
        String where = null;
        Cursor c = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, where, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c;
    }

    // Get a specific row (by rowId)
    public Cursor getRow(long rowId) {
        String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
        Cursor c = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS,
                where, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c;
    }

    // Change an existing row to be equal to new data.
    public boolean updateRow(long rowId, String task, String date) {
        String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
        ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
        newValues.put(KEY_WDH, task);
        newValues.put(KEY_KG, date);
        // Insert it into the database.
        return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, newValues, where, null) != 0;
    }


    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) {
            _db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_SQL);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading application's database from version " + oldVersion
                    + " to " + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data!");

            // Destroy old database:
            _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);

            // Recreate new database:
            onCreate(_db);
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's messy because it looks like it is your identity column and you're trying to remove the gaps.  This isn't good practice, but there is a mechanism for doing it.  Conceptually, this is going to be a 4 step process.

1. Create a new temporary table with the same structure (including the auto-incrementing identity field).
2. Shove the remaining rows from your main table into the temp table.  I was about to write this up, but pseudo code to do this already exists all over.  For example, [here's an answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733714/mysql-update-id-column) with a good one (including a disclaimer that I am seconding about this being a bad idea).
3. Drop your original table.
4. Rename your temp table to the name of your original table.

Note that you are re-writing the entire table every time you do a delete, so this solution doesn't scale well.

A better way to do this would be to add a non-identity integer field to your table where you store your always sequential integer value.  It's going to be your responsibility to maintain this field.  For example...

On initial population of your data, set this field equal to the identity field.

In your "delete a row" routine

```
// Delete a row from the database, by rowId (primary key)
public boolean deleteRow(long rowId) {
    String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
    boolean myReturnValue;
    myReturnValue = db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, where, null) != 0;
    db.execSQL("UPDATE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " SET MyNewNonIdentitySequentialIntegerField = MyNewNonIdentitySequentialIntegerField -1) WHERE KEY_ROWID > " + String.valueOf(rowId) + ";") ;
    return myReturnValue;
}
```

When inserting, or immediately after inserting a new record you'll need to populate it by setting it equal to MAX(MyNewNonIdentitySequentialIntegerField) + 1.